# How to edit widget code?

Tags: javascript, widget, contact-form

im using getsitecontrol's widgets (forms for add subscribers and chat with them in website). Widget by default, get users email and name, but i want to change email input to phone, ( i want get users phone number) .

I add in website only widgets source code  ('//widgets.getsitecontrol.com/74370/script.js') 
and can't do edit on it.

My website url (http://creanima.online)

So , how can i change this input type ?? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You seem to have had some control `input type="tel" maxlength="1000" title="Email" placeholder="Հեռախոս" name="tel" id="gscw_email_input" class="gdmjrb0 g-3e5v7z">` So what is the problem?

Comment: After submit , input is not valid (its shake) , i change type from email to tel , but it doesnt work @mplungjan

Comment: Ask their customer support.

Comment: They havent this function , only email

Comment: Suggest it then. Or reuse a field that does not have validation